# Name for blocky, imprecise illustration style (like Saul Bass, Paul Rand)

Tags: illustration, style-identification, terminology, famous-designers

Simple question. What's a name for that style of illustration that uses characterful slightly childish blocks of bold colour with imprecise edges, as if the illustration had been put together from pieces of coloured paper cut out with blunt scissors?

Some **Paul Rand** examples:

[image]

[From...](http://vi.sualize.us/sparkle_spin_a_about_wordswriten_ann_illustrated_by_found_it_lookybook_paul_illustration_ann_rand_lookybook_picture_cMC.html)

[image]

[From...](http://thesomedayblog.com/2009/08/24/over-the-moon-for-paul-rand/)

Some **Saul Bass** examples (some mix in clipped photos):

[image]

[From...](http://wharferj.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/saul-bass/)

Comment: "Paper cutout" style?

Comment: "All I Need To Know About Graphic Design I Learned In Kindergarten."

Comment: @horatio The trouble with "Paper cutout style" is I find it's more often associated with elaborate things in the style of [Rob Ryan](http://www.misterrob.co.uk/?page_id=2367) these days, which is a very different style. It's the blocky characterful simplicity not the paper-like-ness

Comment: simplicity is often referred to as "minimalism"

Comment: Yup, and I included a reference to minimalism in the question [oops, I thought I did, but actually I deleted it before hitting okay]. Trouble is, if I heard "minimalist papercut" as a description, I'd imagine something like a [subtle delicate finely detailed Rob Ryan-style character surrounded by whitespace](http://chicest.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/p1090244.jpg?w=580&h=435) - not, say, a dramatic and colourful - but low-detail and non-complex - Paul Rand illustration. I guess the key idea is more controlled characterful crudeness than simplicity in the general sense.

Comment: While 'simplicity' *is* often called 'minimalism' it's an abuse of the term, IMHO. As for what to call this style, 'Saul Bass' style is actually fairly accurate, IMHO. ;)

Comment: "Saul Bass" is probably the closest you'll get. I really don't think there is a particular label aside from maybe Modernist Movie Posters such as West Side Story.

Comment: I was just asking the same question. Seems the 'minimalist' flag is about the closest. Anyone else get any closer?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/does-paul-rands-odd-typographic-layout-style-have-a-name/27070#27070

Comment: Hey, this isn't really an answer. Does the answer I gave above help you get closer than minimalist? Otherwise you should either leave a comment on it or start a new question if its different from this one.

Comment: Ahh, where would Hollywood of a certain era have been without it.

Answer (score 5):

They both fall under the Swiss Style of Graphic Design

- [History of Visual Communications from Citrinitas](http://www.citrinitas.com/history_of_viscom/modernists.html)
- [Lessons from Swiss Style Graphic Design from Smashing Mag](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/17/lessons-from-swiss-style-graphic-design/)
- [Swiss / International Style Lecture Slides from Parkland College](http://gds.parkland.edu/gds/!lectures/history/1950/swiss.html)

Comment: Interesting, I'd always thought about the typography and text layout side of the Swiss style, but I see what you mean. "like swiss-style influenced paper cutouts" would probably work for someone who knows their design history (though they'd probably get "like Paul Rand and Saul Bass illustrations" as well)

Comment: While IIRC Rand practically invented Swiss Style, none of the samples in the original question conform to the Swiss Style.